# Problemas con Angular Services Language

Tags: nodejs, angular, vscode, extensiones

Buen dia, desde que cree mi proyecto de angular me aparece el siguiente error (Adjunto imagen)

[Problema Que sale en Angular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tv3Kg.png)

Este error me dice que algo no esta funcionando correctamente en mi Angular. Busque en ChatGPT como solucionarlo y me votaba que tenia que reinstalar todo lo que tuviera que ver con las extenciones de angular, realice este proceso y no me funciono

Mis versiones de angular en este momento son
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tambien intente probar con reinstalar todo Angular CLI y tampoco funciono, ¿ Podrian Ayudarme a solucionar este incomveniente?

El error que dice la terminal es la siguiente

```
[Info  - 2:10:41 p. m.] Angular language server process ID: 11380
[Info  - 2:10:41 p. m.] Using typescript/lib/tsserverlibrary v5.1.6 from c:\Users\DeimosLsK\Documents\Flutter y Angular\Angular\Angular-Base\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsserverlibrary.js
[Info  - 2:10:41 p. m.] Using @angular/language-service v13.3.8 from c:\Users\DeimosLsK\.vscode\extensions\angular.ng-template-13.3.4\node_modules\@angular\language-service\index.js
[Info  - 2:10:41 p. m.] Logging is turned off. To enable, run command 'Open Angular server log'.
[Error - 2:10:44 p. m.] Failed to run ngcc for c:/Users/DeimosLsK/Documents/Flutter y Angular/Angular/Angular-Base/tsconfig.json, language service may not operate correctly:
    Failed to resolve ngcc from c:/Users/DeimosLsK/Documents/Flutter y Angular/Angular/Angular-Base
[Info  - 2:10:44 p. m.] Enabling Ivy language service for c:/Users/DeimosLsK/Documents/Flutter y Angular/Angular/Angular-Base/tsconfig.json.
```

Intente, reinstalar Angular CLI, Intente Reinstalar todas los modulos de node, Intente Reinstalar Extensiones de VS enfocadas a Angular, y no resulto

Comment: Que manía con preguntarle a CHATGPT. Cada vez que lo veo en una pregunta me dan ganas de ponerle un voto negativo ya solo por eso. En fin... Tienes la versión correspondiente a tu versión de angular? Si estás usando las últimas versiones de angular, ya no compilan con ngcc, es posible que por eso la extensión no funcione con ella. Yo uso angular a diario y nunca he visto ese problema con la extensión... claro que depende de cual estés usando y de las versiones. Usa el enlace [edit] y añade la información de versiones anda.

Comment: parece que estas intentando ejecutar un demo que encontraste por ahí, ya instalaste las dependencias con `yarn/npm install` ?

Comment: @Benito-B , Mania no es, es intentar buscar una solución a algo que no encontre primero en Stack Overflow ? si das soluciones asi mejor no las respondas, muchas gracias

Ya actualice por si te interesa

Comment: @LPZadkiel, Si señor, el proyecto es mio de un curso pero en las especificaciones del curso no sale alguna solución del mismo debido a que es un error de una Extensión de VS, por lo que

Comment: Actualiza la extensión a la v16.1.8 y se soluciona el problema. ChatGPT no tiene ni idea de qué hace, venir aquí a pedir ayuda porque chatgpt no sabe ayudarte es como venir a decir "no he hecho absolutamente nada de investigación". Se investigan los problemas en google, no en chatgpt. Entre google, stackoverflow y los repositorios normalmente siempre se encuentra respuesta. En este caso, en el propio repositorio de la extensión de angular-language-service hay un ticket abierto donde exponen el problema que hay en angular 16 con la extensión, solución: actualizala.

Comment: Usá ChatGPT solo cuando sabés lo que estás haciendo. Preguntar _a ciegas_ allí es jugar a la suerte: librerías desfasadas, código inaplicable en el lenguaje en cuestión... Que te tire una respuesta que _parece_ coherente no quiere decir que la sea.

Comment: @Benito-b Voy a probar lo que me dices, pero de todas maneras decir que no investigo cuando en la misma publicación te lo digo que si investigue me parece totalmente desfasado y ignorante de tu parte 

Gracias !

Comment: @padaleiana, claro que si pero en cuestión no estoy preguntando sobre un codigo en especial ya que para eso mismo lo estoy creando yo, estoy pregutnando a la comunidad sobre una extensión que no funciona correctamente y si tienen alguna manera de solucionarlo

Comment: @Ru'izStevensKn Me alegra que lo arreglases, y si has investigado o no, solo lo sabes tú pero en tu pregunta la única "investigación" que mencionas es preguntar en chatgpt... Por aquí eso es comparable a decirnos que le has preguntado a una magic 8 ball, una bola de esas que saca mensajes aleatorios. No cuenta como investigación. En programación, sobre todo cuando usas las últimas versiones de algún framework, es siempre muy importante usar también las últimas versiones de las herramientas que usamos, pues suelen estar ajustadas para las versiones actuales de los principales frameworks :)

Answer (score 0):

Buenas a todos los que lean

Resolvi el problema que tuve, realizando lo siguiente

Actualizando VS a una versión mucho mas reciente
como decia @Benito-B en respuestas anteriores actualizando la extensión

Ademas se requiere de reinstalar las dependencias del proyecto del node_modules, recomiendo realizar esto para asi evitar cualquier otro inconveniente proveniente de alguna dependencia

Gracias a todos por sus aportes.